# Vue.js 2.0 filters in text interpolations

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I'm using vue.js 2.0 (standalone) build.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <p> ${ number | results_found } </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        number: 0,
    },
    filters: {
        results_found: function(value) {
            console.log(value + " results found!");
            return value + " results found!";
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

I changed the delimiters (see above) so that they would not conflict with Django's templating syntax.

When I run this I see in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: results_found (found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)
0 results found!
```

Yet in the HTML all I see is:

```
0
```

What am I doing wrong? All new to Vue.js, by the way.

EDIT: Also how do I "name" components for better debugging? My filter is on my instance, not a component...

Comment: This look fine, I created a fiddle, it is working as expected. Might be Django's template conflicting with Vue.js https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/15554/

Comment: this works fine for me too.

Comment: update: just realized this is in console: `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: results_found (found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)`. Perhaps that helps?